# Can I write this JQuery statement cleaner?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following:

```
var box = $(".MyCheckBox");

if (box[0].checked)
{
    // Do something
}
else
{
    // Do something else
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this using filters or something?

I know I can go:

```
$(".MyCheckBox")
    .filter(function(index) {
         return this.checked;
     })
    .each(function() {
         // do something
     });
```

But I need to do something in the else statement... easier way of doing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in `:checked` selector:

```
$(".MyCheckBox:checked").each(function() {
  //Do something with checked ones..
});
$(".MyCheckBox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
  //Do something with unchecked ones..
});
```

Or filter in the each similar to what you have:

```
$(".MyCheckBox").each(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    //Do something with checked ones..
  } else {
    //Do something with unchecked ones..
  }
});
```

Or if say you wanted to toggle a class, then use a different approach, this would give the `active` class to the checked ones:

```
$(".MyCheckBox").each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

**Update**
Based on comments if you want just raw speed:

```
$(".MyCheckBox").each(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    //Do something with checked ones..
  } else {
    //Do something with unchecked ones..
  }
});
```

Comment: I believe using the :checked selector is faster than using attr.

Comment: :checked is far, far slower than attr on the test I did (http://www.jsfiddle.net/CTu7a/)

Comment: what about just doing this.checked?

Comment: @Polaris878 - `this.checked` is **far** faster than either method.  But you're talking about an infinitesimally small difference here unless dealing with thousands of checkboxes, so what's more readable is probably better.

Comment: I'll be dealing with up to a couple hundred checkboxes so it might matter :)

Comment: @Polaris878 - In that case, `$(".MyCheckbox").filter(function() { return this.checked; })` is about as fast as you'll get in selecting the checked ones, or use it in the each/if, either way.  In my answer swap ` if($(this).is(":checked")) {` in the second code block for `if(this.checked) {`, I'll update with this example.

Answer (score 5):

attr('checked') returns the checked value of the first element anyway, so no [0] malarky.

```
if ($(".MyCheckBox").attr('checked')) {
 // Do something
} else {
 // else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with Nick's updated answer above, but would like to suggest that you complete your selector. i.e.,

```
$('input.myCheckBox').each(function(){
    // tralalala...
}
```

... just for the fact that it makes your initial jQuery selection a bit faster. I mean, since we're debating about speed and all. ^_^